# Unload the some of projects from Visual Studio and check-in via TFS version Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I want to unload some of my projects from Visual Studio in the same solution and then check-in via TFS so that my colleague can get the solution via TFS with unloaded project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way that I can share loaded/unloaded configuration (settings) in source control like `TFS`.
In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019#solution-filter-files) shows how we can create a filtered solution and share with our colleagues.

Notice that filtered solution has a ***.slnf*** extension and everyone wants to use loaded/unloaded configuration must open a ***.slnf*** file instead of ***.sln*** file

Answer (score 1):

Which projects are loaded (or unloaded) as part of a solution is stored in user settings (.suo in some versions of VS).   These are generally not checked into source control systems (like TFS) because they are not related to the build or configuration of the solution.

Comment: How do I know the project is unloaded? I want to use condition in Reference tag in web.config to switch between class library (.dll) and debugable project

Comment: I found a way in Visual 2019 to do that. We can filter the solution and create a `.slnf` file and check-in by source control. Take a look at my answer.